# My spark application hangs at a point on performing join operation on two data frames

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark, I am doing join on two data frames on 'not equal to' condition. At a point my program stops and never run further neither gives an exception.

I am using a simple text file containing 100000 records.

I have a non lazy method 'collectAsList' in my program, which causes join to be performed.

Here is the stack trace:

```
15/10/14 09:25:36 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 25.0 with 2 tasks
15/10/14 09:25:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.38:50065 (size: 4.7 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
15/10/14 09:25:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.38:50065 (size: 4.8 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
15/10/14 09:25:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.37:48062 (size: 4.8 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
15/10/14 09:25:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.37:48062 (size: 4.7 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
15/10/14 09:25:39 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.38:50065 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
15/10/14 09:25:39 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.37:48062 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
```

Comment: I have tried increasing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions upto 1000 but It didn't worked.

Comment: It's hanging because it's trying to collect your df into a list which will definitely blow up the driver memory eventually (OOM) Avoid collect and apply a simple count action per example.

Comment: But I need to collect the data frame as list? what are the alternatives?

Comment: Also I think problem is in join operation because it is a inner join with not equal to condition, which results (n*n)-n columns, particularly in my case which is to be appx. 10000000000 records. Also I agree with you as collectAsList is a non lazy operation which forces driver to execute all lazy operations.

Comment: Why do you need to collect the Dataframe? I'm not convinced and it's also a bad practice.

Comment: I found out that the problem isn't with the collectAsList method it's with the large dataframe we are using? As it is an action it forces the program to perform join which in my case is heavy computation.